# Rails 2 application find current_user last five tweets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, tweets

I am working on Rails 2 application

I have installed twitter gem

I want list of last five tweets

I dont know how to get the list, although I installed twitter gem

Please Help Me.

**EDIT**

I have created `twitter.rb` and entered the following details

```
Twitter.configure do |config|     
   config.consumer_key = ""     
   config.consumer_secret = ""      
   config.oauth_token = ""      
   config.oauth_token_secret = ""       
end
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: can we try something like 
 @status = Twitter.user_timeline("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=#{@name}")

Comment: do you have all the keys

Comment: Read this https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Answer (score 2):

Googling the solution it was not that hard to find:

[4 Ways to Retrieve a Twitter List Timeline](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2010/2/1/4-ways-to-retrieve-a-twitter-list-timeline/)

Comment: Have you installed the gem? And which of the methods did you used?